# How to upload video to Microsoft Video Indexer(mic cognitive service api) through the api call?

Tags: c#, azure, video, azure-cognitive-services

How to post video to endpoint of the videoindexer "https://videobreakdown.azure-api.net/Breakdowns/Api/Partner/Breakdowns".

```
static async void MakeRequest()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "mykey");


        // Request parameters
        queryString["name"] = "name";
        queryString["privacy"] = "Private";
        var uri = "https://videobreakdown.azure-api.net/Breakdowns/Api/Partner/Breakdowns?" + queryString;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body

        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open(@"file", FileMode.Open)), "file", "filename");

            try
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

        }

    }
```

I am getting "A Task was canceled" exception. Please help.

The api works fine when i am using videourl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because while trying to upload, my request was getting timed out.

I added

```
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
```

and now it's fixed.